# Need help understanding Coldfusion URL Referral

Tags: url, coldfusion

I have a ColdFusion site on which I need to display different text based on how the user got to the page.

I.e.,

```
<cfif user comes from sitemap.cfm>
    Display this text
<cfelse>
    display this text
</cfif>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to look at the CGI environment variables, specifically `HTTP_REFERER` (and no, that isn't misspelled -- or, I should say, the name of the CGI variable is misspelled).

I believe the value of `HTTP_REFERER` will contain the entire URL, including the query string, so you'll have to parse it -- or perhaps use `CONTAINS` or `findNoCase()` in your `<cfif>` statement:

```
<cfif findNoCase("sitemap.cfm", cgi.HTTP_REFERER)>
    Display this text
<cfelse>
    display this text
</cfif>
```

It's important to note that the value of `HTTP_REFERER` will be empty if you're going from `HTTP` to `HTTPS` -- and vice-versa, I believe.

Comment: ... and HTTP_REFERER can also be blocked or spoofed. So as with any client supplied value, do not rely on it for anything important.

Answer (score 1):

Using `CGI.HTTP_REFERER` is one possible solution as mentioned by [David Faber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1236090/david-faber). It's the easiest way and I would recommend it.

If you don't, or can't, trust the `CGI.HTTP_REFERER` value for some reason, then another solution is to implement a kind of tracking of your user (more precisely of his http request). For example you could :

- Use a (key,value) in the `Session` scope (and not `Request` scope) e.g By implementing it in an `onRequestStart(String targetPage)` inside your `Application.cfm` (or directly in sitemap.cfm ?). Then do what you need or want to do depending on the `targetPage` value and your `SESSION[key]`value.
- Use the same technique but with the `COOKIE` scope (or with `cfcookie` ?). Depends on the http request workflow...

I think there may be other tracking techniques and it's up to you :-)

Comment: I don't think the **REQUEST** scope will work since it is destroyed with every page - it won't be available on the next page (which is, I think, what the OP is looking for). **SESSION** is a much better way to do it.

Comment: You're right ! Something like SESSION["sitemap_visited"] is better ;-)